# How can i add element with attributes to SVG using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael, highcharts

i'm using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) , the chart result is a collection of SVG elements and i  was trying to add some elements to this `SVG` using jquery

Here is what i have tried

```
function(chart) { // on chart load complete 
  $("#highcharts-0 Svg").
   append(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect"));
   $("#highcharts-0 Svg").find("rect").
   attr({x : 100 , y:100 , width : 100 , height : 100 });
   console.log($("#highcharts-0 Svg "));
                  });
```

i can't really say if this is working or not , all i can see is  a `<rect></rect>` element in my `DOM` with no `attr` 
another notice is when i hover on this element using chrome console it shows the rec on `x-0 , y=0`,

[image]

i have an idea that jquery does not append svg elements hop i'm wrong

**Question** How can i add element with attributes to SVG using jquery

**EDIT**

with help now i have `id` for the `rect` element 
then i tried to add `attr` with using the `id` , but failed

[ScreenShot](http://screencast.com/t/7m1q9OR1sfZ5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Highcharts also has a drawing API that you can use to draw rectangles. This works also for VML. Check out http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#renderer => rect and live sample at http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-rect-on-chart/.

Comment: ARE you Torstein Hønsi ???  ... what i was trying to do is finding a way to add elements to the chart using inline Jquery or Raphael js , my other question is does this API allow you to render animation to the elements ...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#element), there're no attributes `rx` and `ry`, try to change it to `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Rectangles have x and y attributes. rx and ry are used on circles.

Also, are you sure your selector is correct? You might want to lowercase the 'Svg'

** edit **
The rect in your screenshot doesn't have any of the attributes assigned. There's no width or height, or x/y positions. You should try giving the rectangle an id when appending it, and querying for it using that same id.

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElementNS

You can do it like this:

```
var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","rect");
rect.id = 'your_id_here';
```

Then append the rect through the normal route.

Note that, since you have the raw dom element, you might be able to assign your other properties there as well. e.g.:

```
rect.x = 100;
rect.y = 100;
rect.fill = 'blue';
```

Comment: i edit my question , the selector is correct see the screenshot , i already added the rect tag inside the svg

Comment: the id part works fine , i used $("#myrect").attr("x", "100");  it doesn't do any thing

Comment: Do you have another screenshot for the rectangle with the id?

Comment: Hmm. My only guess is that it needs the pair of x and y. Try giving it a fill as well. See if you can assign them in programmatically before appending. Then just append the fully defined rectangle with query. Don't try modifying it afterwards.